# Is the sup norm a differentiable function on $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

> Is the sup norm a differentiable function on $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$?
>
> Hint: Consider $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(u) = max_{t \in [a,b]} \lvert u(t) \rvert$. Can you find a function $h \in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$ such that $\lvert\lvert u + h \rvert\rvert \sim \lvert\lvert u-h \rvert\rvert \sim \lvert\lvert u \rvert\rvert + \varepsilon?$ If so, what does this imply?

I guess it is clear that $h := u + \varepsilon$ fullfilles these criteria, but I do not see how this should help here.

Comment: No norm is differentiable at $0$. Did the question specify on $C[a,b]\setminus \{0\}$ instead?

Comment: The way that the hint is phrased suggests that the question's author expects you to find an $h$ such that $\lVert u + \epsilon h\rVert, \lVert u - \epsilon h\rVert =\lVert u \rVert + \epsilon + o(\epsilon)$, in which case the directional derivative $\delta F[u; h] = \delta F[u; -h] = 1$, in which case $F$ cannot be differentiable, since that would require $\delta F[u; \cdot]$ to be linear. But I think that you can only find such an $h$ if $u''(x^*) = 0$, where $x^*$ is the maximiser of $u$.

Comment: @TheoBendit: No, the question concerns only $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$.